# Modify JSON data with python

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot in python and I have a command that scrape every users on my discord server and put them in a JSON file, I have it set as if a person already exists in the JSON file then it adds them a second time to their section but I have problems making it. This is the code I use to put everything in the JSON file:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import json
from datetime import date

@commands.command()
async def forceScrape(ctx):
    schizo = 1133822869177126942 #my discord id
    debugchannel = bot.get_channel(1134732572816068628) #debug channel
    if ctx.message.author.id == schizo: #check if the user is me
        with open("users.json", "r") as f:
            users = json.load(f) #load json file

        for members in ctx.guild.members:
            currentDate = date.today() #getting current date
            usersid = members.id #getting every memebers' ids
            names = members.name #getting every members' name
            if str(usersid) in users:
                users[usersid] = [{f"{users[str(usersid)]}\n" + f"{currentDate}":names}] #updating users[usersid] to add new datas
                await debugchannel.send(f"ID: {usersid} NAME: {names} || was updated") #send a message in the debug channel
            else:
                users[usersid] = [{f"{currentDate}":names}] #add new datas in users[usersid]
                await debugchannel.send(f"ID: {usersid} NAME: {names} || was added") #send a message in debug channel

        with open("users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f, indent=4) #put everything in users.json

        await debugchannel.send("Users have been scraped to users.json")
    else:
        await ctx.reply("You do not have permissions to execute that command")
```

and this is how it looks when it adds new data to an already existing user:

```
{
    "1133822869177126942": [
        {
            "[{'2023-07-30': 'schizophrenic'}]\n2023-07-30": "schizophrenic"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to have it look like this:

```
{
    "1133822869177126942": [
        {
            "2023-07-30": "schizophrenic"
        },
        {
            "2023-07-30": "schizophrenic"
        }
    ]
}
```

I searched for multiple ways to accomplish that but can't find anything to have it to work so this is my last resort.

I detailed the code as much as possible to make it easier for you to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all your dictionary is a string, you can't have duplucates in a dictionary, and you can't have a dictionary in a dictionary like that.

Is this what you want? (will not allow duplicate keys)

```json
{
    "1133822869177126942": {
        "2023-07-30": "schizophrenic",
        "2023-07-31": "schizophrenic"
    }

}
```

Or do you want to use a list? (will allow duplicates)

```json
{
    "1133822869177126942": [
        {"2023-07-30": "schizophrenic"},
        {"2023-07-30": "schizophrenic"}

    ]
}
```

This is a formatting problem.  Figure out your format then build your code based on the format.

From what I see I assume you should use a list, the second option.

If you want to use nested dictionaries format it properly https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_nested.asp

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you for replying to me, I want the first exemple but I get something looking like this: "1133822869177126942": {
        "{'2023-07-30': 'schizophrenic'}\n2023-07-30": "schizophrenic"
    }

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary.  So what is it exactly that you want?  Will you have duplicate dates or not?

Comment: Yes, I'll have duplicate dates, duplicates are not a problem for me, I'm trying to have them sort as they should but can't figure out how to achieve that result

Comment: Oh my bad I just understood what you meant, I need the 2nd result then

Comment: Ok then change your code to use a list

Comment: Okay I changed my code to use lists, looks like this now:

"1133822869177126942": [
        {
            "[{'2023-07-30': 'schizophrenic'}]\n2023-07-30": "schizophrenic"
        }
    ]

Comment: post code in ticks it's difficult to read text `"1133822869177126942": [ { "[{'2023-07-30': 'schizophrenic'}]\n2023-07-30": "schizophrenic" } ]` https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#code

Comment: I edited my original post for you to look at it !

Comment: Dont concatenate to add to list `[{f"{users[str(usersid)]}\n" + f"{currentDate}":names}]`, use append. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_add.asp

Comment: I think it's this instead `users[usersid].append(f"{currentDate}":names)`, but try it to make sure because I can't test your code.

Comment: Sorry I think it's this `users[usersid].append({f"{currentDate}":names})`